# SQL Server Database Restore with ReadXML

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've backup from a sqlserver created with this procedure:

```
protected void WriteXML(string tableName)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM
        [" + tableName + "];", cnn))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, tableName);
            ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\" + tableName + ".xml");
            ds.WriteXmlSchema(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\" + tableName + ".xslt");
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to restore this database. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Besides using the native Backup/Restore method?

Comment: The more common means would be to export the data to a flat file in the form of insert statements, so you could open the file either with Management Studio, Toad, or SQLCMD to run & insert the data into another instance.

Comment: Funny that you write out the XML schema to a .XSLT file - that's a XSL transformation - something completely different. XML schema files are typically stored in `file.xsd` files (extension .xsd)

Comment: Happy to make you fun :D. But actually I don't use these files for anything. Anyway, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here is the solution based on [eggheadcafe.com](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10082226/i-need-to-read-xml-and-insert-data-of-the-elements-in-to-sql-server.aspx) post

```
protected void ReadXML(string tableName)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("App_Data\\" + tableName + ".xml");
    using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
    {
        sbc.DestinationTableName = tableName;
        sbc.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[tableName]);
        sbc.Close();
    }
}
```

Also we have to SET IDENTITY_INSERT [tableName] ON/OFF if table has an identity column.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, no.

- you'll have foreign keys and triggers to think about (order of tables)
- data will have changed during the backup (missing parent or children)
- you won't have backed up system tables and metadata
- you won't have backed up security

Use SQL Server native backup and restore like everyone else. Sorry if this is brutal, but I've never known anyone to try and backup a database like this.

After comments:

Why not ask your host to FTP (etc) a backup to you?

Also, if you can backup every table in the database via a web site and it becomes accessible then it means you have poor security...

Comment: Thanks but I simply have to create database with example data. I don't need the relations and other stuff. Just need to know how database was designed and what is stored in it.

Comment: You would need relations to capture table relationships, uniqueness,  data integrity etc. You also imply you don't have normal access to this database but can still dump schema and contents... why not ask someone for a copy of it.